# Swift: Из структуры в JSON без Codable

Tags: swift

Всем привет! Сторонняя сдк десереализует json, приходящий c сервера, в структуру, которая подписана под Decodable, а мне нужно наоборот,  из нее получить json строку. Подписать сдкашную структуру под Codable, понятное дело, я не могу

```
    struct User: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let verification: Sdk.VerificationType 
}

print(user)

// User(id: "12345", name: "Max", verification: Sdk.User.VerificationType.notRequired)
```

Есть варианты, как из этого получить json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подписать нет. Но что есть `Codable`? Это `Decodable` и `Encodable`. Так что можно её просто расширить:

```swift
extension User: Encodable {}
```

И загонять в `JSONEncoder`.

---

Расширенный пример:

```swift
extension User: Encodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case verification = "sdk_verification_type" //для примера
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(verification, forKey: .verification) // Для Sdk.VerificationType в зависимости от надобности свой Encodable/конвертацию в другой формат
    }
}
```

Comment: error: Implementation of 'Encodable' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension in a different file to the type

Comment: @villyVo, `func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws` Вы реализовали, которая требуется по протоколу?

Comment: @villyVo, добрался до Xcode, обновил ответ.